# Visa needed for transit in Heathrow?

Tags: visas, transit, datv, ukrainian-citizens

My wife is Ukrainian citizen with Romanian residency permit. We have tickets for a flight Madrid-Heathrow-Seoul:

> jue 05/01/2017  Iberia  IB 3160
>   Turista    09:10 Madrid Adolfo Suárez Barajas Terminal: 4  10:40 Londres
>   Heathrow Terminal: 5
>     jue 05/01/2017  British Airways     BA 0017
>   Turista    13:00 Londres Heathrow Terminal: 5  08:55 Seoul Incheon   >Internacional

I want to understand if she needs a transit visa or not.

My understanding so far is that there is the DATV visa which can be used if you will not go through UK border control, but:

1. I don't know if this is the case or not (we will not have to recheck-in our luggage, but is there any other Border Control that we might have to pass - i.e. if the terminals will change and not both flights will depart from Terminal 5?)
2. According to [GOV.UK](https://www.gov.uk/transit-visa/direct-airside-transit-visa) "You don’t need to apply for one if you have: an EEA family permit".

Which seems to be the case.

So in this situation she is not required any visa at all?

Comment: A Romanian residence permit is not an EEA family permit.  The EEA family permit is a special visa issued by the UK to family members of EU, EEA, and Swiss citizens.  They're free of charge, so if you are an EU/EEA/Swiss citizen, and you decide she needs a visa for the transit, this will be your least expensive option.

Answer (score 1):

DATVs are not needed for citizens of all visa countries. Only a specific subset of nationalities that require a visa to enter the UK also require a DATV.

The UK government [operates a "Do I need a visa" check website.](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa) Putting in the details that I believe apply to your wife (Ukrainian citizen, transit, not passing passport control [this assumes you are on a single ticket]), [then it says](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/ukraine/transit/no):

> ### You won’t need a visa to come to the UK

Note that a standard Romanian Residence Permit is not an EEA family permit. An EEA family permit will describe itself as one.